# Overriding google recaptcha css to make it responsive

Tags: css, responsive-design, recaptcha

I installed [Google Recaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php)  in a site (not a Wordpress site or Joomla) So do not offer any WP plugins or Joomla Extension :)

My problem is, the site is responsive and recaptcha is not. When I use Firebug to find its styles I realized that not only the library that Google provides does not contain the css files, and I can't override them in my custom-styles.css file because Google, very thoughtfully, applied the `!important` selector hack to EVERYTHING in their css, but I even tried classing it so that I can make a breach and hopefully override Google's styles but then the plugin doesn't work:(

Any ideas?

p.s. I am not using a different re-captcha either. Sorry. I'm sure there are some recaptcha geeks out here ;)

Here is the HTML. This is what the recaptcha.php renders from the server. THIS IS NOT WHAT i I HAVE IN THE ACTUAL PHP PAGE...(Don't have a CSS, and that is the main problem)

```
<div id="recaptcha_widget_div" style="" class=" recaptcha_nothad_incorrect_sol recaptcha_isnot_showing_audio"><div id="recaptcha_area"><table id="recaptcha_table" class="recaptchatable recaptcha_theme_red"> 
  <tbody>
     <tr> 
        <td colspan="6" class="recaptcha_r1_c1"></td> 
     </tr> 
     <tr> 
        <td class="recaptcha_r2_c1"></td> 
        <td colspan="4" class="recaptcha_image_cell">
            <center><div id="recaptcha_image" style="width: 300px; height: 57px;">
                  <img id="recaptcha_challenge_image" alt="reCAPTCHA challenge image" height="57" width="300" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/image?c=03AHJ_VutTaFjCI-gV3f3W2_M6gix7arVpF-9EOz-f773U5LmDrl33mKCn9wMXYGe0t8-xy-1HD0ysHzOI_NYyOtxOxD_a4Jj5G5h4bDMalKBQ5PDJaaE6ur8K44ilzimisHHYX6xZJ4y9xeuP6lT4vQa59-nNPju3VrlolnYgbM6oKgD7el1Rr9cpbRojjc_2zFraHkTjxyUU"></div>
            </center>
         </td> 
         <td class="recaptcha_r2_c2"></td> 
      </tr> 
      <tr> 
         <td rowspan="6" class="recaptcha_r3_c1"></td> 
         <td colspan="4" class="recaptcha_r3_c2"></td> 
         <td rowspan="6" class="recaptcha_r3_c3"></td> 
      </tr> 
      <tr> 
         <td rowspan="3" class="recaptcha_r4_c1" height="49"> 
              <div class="recaptcha_input_area"> 
                  <span id="recaptcha_challenge_field_holder" style="display: none;">                      
                      <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_challenge_field" id="recaptcha_challenge_field" value="03AHJ_VutTaFjCI-gV3f3W2_M6gix7arVpF-9EOz-f773U5LmDrl33mKCn9wMXYGe0t8-xy-1HD0ysHzOI_NYyOtxOxD_a4Jj5G5h4bDMalKBQ5PDJaaE6ur8K44ilzimisHHYX6xZJ4y9xeuP6lT4vQa59-nNPju3VrlolnYgbM6oKgD7el1Rr9cpbRojjc_2zFraHkTjxyUU"></span>
                      <input name="recaptcha_response_field" id="recaptcha_response_field" type="text" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" placeholder="Type the text" autocomplete="off" style="font-style: italic;"> 
                           <span id="recaptcha_privacy" class="recaptcha_only_if_privacy"><a href="http://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/" target="_blank">Privacy &amp; Terms</a></span> 
              </div> 
          </td> 
          <td rowspan="4" class="recaptcha_r4_c2"></td> 
          <td><a id="recaptcha_reload_btn" title="Get a new challenge">
              <img id="recaptcha_reload" width="25" height="17" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/img/red/refresh.gif" alt="Get a new challenge"></a></td> 
          <td rowspan="4" class="recaptcha_r4_c4"></td> 
      </tr> 
      <tr> 
          <td><a id="recaptcha_switch_audio_btn" class="recaptcha_only_if_image" title="Get an audio challenge">
               <img id="recaptcha_switch_audio" width="25" height="16" alt="Get an audio challenge" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/img/red/audio.gif"></a><a id="recaptcha_switch_img_btn" class="recaptcha_only_if_audio" title="Get a visual challenge">
               <img id="recaptcha_switch_img" width="25" height="16" alt="Get a visual challenge" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/img/red/text.gif"></a>
          </td> 
      </tr> 
      <tr> 
          <td><a id="recaptcha_whatsthis_btn" title="Help">
               <img id="recaptcha_whatsthis" width="25" height="16" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/img/red/help.gif" alt="Help"></a>
          </td> 
      </tr> 
      <tr> 
          <td class="recaptcha_r7_c1"></td> <td class="recaptcha_r8_c1"></td> 
      </tr> 
  </tbody>
 </table> 
</div> 
</div>
```

This is what I do have in the page

```
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $publickey = "your_public_key"; // you got this from the signup page
  echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
```

And here is my problem

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Changed auto height and media query

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
    #recaptcha_challenge_image{
    margin: 0 !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
    }
    #recaptcha_response_field
    {
    margin: 0 !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
    }
    .recaptchatable #recaptcha_image {
    margin: 0 !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
    }
    .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r1_c1, 
    .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r3_c1, 
    .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r3_c2, 
    .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r7_c1, 
    .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r8_c1, 
    .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r3_c3, 
    .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r2_c1, 
    .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r4_c1, 
    .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r4_c2, 
    .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r4_c4, 
    .recaptchatable .recaptcha_image_cell {

    margin: 0 !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    background: none !important;
    height: auto !important;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 19):

For reCAPTCHA (requires jQuery):

```
$(function(){
  function rescaleCaptcha(){
    var width = $('.g-recaptcha').parent().width();
    var scale;
    if (width < 302) {
      scale = width / 302;
    } else{
      scale = 1.0; 
    }

    $('.g-recaptcha').css('transform', 'scale(' + scale + ')');
    $('.g-recaptcha').css('-webkit-transform', 'scale(' + scale + ')');
    $('.g-recaptcha').css('transform-origin', '0 0');
    $('.g-recaptcha').css('-webkit-transform-origin', '0 0');
  }

  rescaleCaptcha();
  $( window ).resize(function() { rescaleCaptcha(); });

});
```

This basically checks your browser width and depends the scale it should be transformed too. Best solution around at this point.

Screenshots result (full width, smaller width, smallest width):

[image: Full width]

[image: Smaller width]

[image: Smallest width]

Comment: This prevents it displaying in several browsers: Chrome, Brave, Safari, etc. Test before you post.

Comment: Works in every modern browser. Test before you post ;)

Comment: I should have said that DNN was in the mix ;-)

Answer (score 3):

In my case I decreased the scale of it and I force some **horizontal alignment on center** through **Bootstrap 4** grid system. 
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjIC9.png) to see the result.

Code:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
     <div class="col g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="check_reCaptcha_doc_to_set_this" style="width: 304px !important; max-width: 304px !important; -ms-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8); -webkit-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8); transform: scale(0.8, 0.8); margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Google has complete documentation on how to style recaptcha forms here:

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display

and you can completely override the html/css they provide with your own.

Comment: This is no longer true, Google Recaptcha 2.0 actually does not allow theme customization: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713505/recaptcha-api-v2-styling

Answer (score 2):

You may want to add some CSS styling but we opted for removing everything that wasn't necessary.

Add this code to your css file :

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
        #recaptcha_challenge_image{
        margin: 0 !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        }
        #recaptcha_response_field
        {
        margin: 0 !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        }
        .recaptchatable #recaptcha_image {
        margin: 0 !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        }
        .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r1_c1, 
        .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r3_c1, 
        .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r3_c2, 
        .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r7_c1, 
        .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r8_c1, 
        .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r3_c3, 
        .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r2_c1, 
        .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r4_c1, 
        .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r4_c2, 
        .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r4_c4, 
        .recaptchatable .recaptcha_image_cell {

        margin: 0 !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        background: none !important;
        }

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this one. [Google responsive reCAPTCHA](http://hkpatel201.blogspot.in/2015/06/google-responsive-recaptcha.html)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Works well. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution with media queries. I use scale to scale it down to a reasonable size for mobile.

**A simple and effective solution:**

```
@media (max-width:575px) {
    #rc-imageselect, .g-recaptcha {
        transform:scale(0.77);
        transform-origin:0 0;
        margin-bottom: -20px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is that you use the google recaptcha and use this css code to make responsive,

```
#rc-imageselect, .g-recaptcha {
   display: inline; //the most important
}

#rc-imageselect{
   max-width: 100%;
}

.g-recaptcha>div>div{
   width: 100% !important;
   height: 78px;
   transform:scale(0.77); //the code to rescale the captcha obtained in this page
   webkit-transform:scale(0.77);
   text-align: center;
   position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add some transform style for the specific device you needed:

```
 @media only screen and (max-width : 767px)     {

 #rc-imageselect, .g-recaptcha {
    transform: scale(0.77);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.77);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best workaround I have found in 2017/2018 :

```
.g-recaptcha > div {
    width: 100% !important;
}

.g-recaptcha iframe {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Indeed works just as well as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simple you have to copy style attribute from below code to your code then your problem will solved.

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-theme="light" data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXXXXXX" 
style="transform:scale(0.77);-webkit-transform:scale(0.77);transform-origin:0 0;- 
webkit-transform-origin:0 0;"></div>
```

For more details open this [Link](https://geekgoddess.com/how-to-resize-the-google-nocaptcha-recaptcha/)

Answer (score 0):

Building off [Jan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3829520/jan) answer and [Siraj Khan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2427148/siraj-khan) answer, I added some more styling to format the buttons on the right side that allow you to refresh the image, play out loud, learn more, and read privacy & terms easier.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
  #recaptcha_challenge_image{
    margin: 0 !important;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  #recaptcha_response_field {
    margin: 0 !important;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  .recaptchatable #recaptcha_image {
    margin: 0 !important;
    width: 95% !important;
  }
  .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r1_c1,
  .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r3_c1,
  .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r3_c2,
  .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r7_c1,
  .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r8_c1,
  .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r3_c3,
  .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r2_c1,
  .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r4_c1,
  .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r4_c2,
  .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r4_c4,
  .recaptchatable .recaptcha_image_cell {
    margin: 0 !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    background: none !important;
  }
  #recaptcha_table tbody tr td {
    padding: 0 !important;
    width: 75px;
  }
  .recaptchatable .recaptcha_image_cell {
    padding-right: 0 !important;
  }
  #recaptcha_privacy a {
    line-height: 1.2em;
  }
  span#recaptcha_privacy {
    width: 50px;
  }
}
```

[image: Google recaptcha responsive CSS]

Answer (score 0):

may be this could help you use transform on your main div where u call recaptcha

```
transform: scale(0.75);
transform-origin: left top;
```

Answer (score 0):

Good night, I created this code in jquery, hope it helps, you can modify the values

```js
<script>
  
  $(window).resize(function(){

var widthInput = $('input').width()



const defaulCaptchaWidth = 294.5651;
var total = widthInput * 100/defaulCaptchaWidth/100
total = widthInput <= 664 ? total+0.035 : total


$('.gc-recaptcha').css('transform','scale('+total+')');

  });

  $(document).ready(function(){
    var widthInput = $('input').width()



const defaulCaptchaWidth = 294.5651;
var total = widthInput * 100/defaulCaptchaWidth/100
total = widthInput <= 664 ? total+0.035 : total




$('.gc-recaptcha').css('transform','scale('+total+')'); 
  })

//   transform:scale(1.26) !important;

  </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

just need to organize`

```html
  <div class="container">
  <form>

  
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="|*SEU-SITE-KEY*|"></div>
  </div>
```

```css
.gc-recaptcha {


transform-origin:0 0 !important;

}
```

`

Comment: add your code  <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>

Answer (score 0):

> try this for answer part:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
iframe > ::after, ::before{
    position: relative;
    width: 100% !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    right:0 !important;
}
```

}

and this to checkbox part(note that recaptchaDiv is id of your added captcha container div) :

```
#recaptchaDiv {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
}

.g-recaptcha > div {
    width: 100% !important;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: -1px;
}

    .g-recaptcha > div > div {
        width: 100% !important;
        transform: scale(0.73);
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        top: -1px;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

Good night, I created this code in jquery, hope it helps, you can modify the values

```js
<script>
  
  $(window).resize(function(){

var widthInput = $('input').width()



const defaulCaptchaWidth = 294.5651;
var total = widthInput * 100/defaulCaptchaWidth/100
total = widthInput <= 664 ? total+0.035 : total

var teste = widthInput <= 664 ? "Sim" : "nao";
console.log(total);


$('.gc-reset').css('transform','scale('+total+')');

  });

  $(document).ready(function(){
    var widthInput = $('input').width()



const defaulCaptchaWidth = 294.5651;
var total = widthInput * 100/defaulCaptchaWidth/100
total = widthInput <= 664 ? total+0.035 : total

var teste = widthInput <= 664 ? "Sim" : "nao";
console.log(total);


$('.gc-reset').css('transform','scale('+total+')'); 
  })

//   transform:scale(1.26) !important;

  </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

just need to organize

Comment: You should add more explanation on how to use your code. Plus, this assume OP can/want to run JQuery. A pure CSS solution in this case would probably be more appropriate.