# ReCaptcha API v2 Styling

Tags: javascript, css, captcha, recaptcha

I have not had much success finding how to style Google's new recaptcha (v2). The eventual goal is to make it responsive, but I am having difficulty applying styling for even simple things like width.

Their [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display) does not appear to give any specifics on how to control styling at all other than the *theme* parameter, and simple CSS & JavaScript solutions haven't worked for me.

Basically, I need to be able to apply CSS to Google's new version of reCaptcha. Using JavaScript with it is acceptable.

Comment: I have the same success :(

Comment: Being able to apply custom CSS to Google's new v2 reCaptcha, released just this past December, and have it work in all modern desktop and mobile browsers (and IE8 even if it is some hack).

Comment: Its width is 300px, which fits into mobile view, what kind of responsivness do you try to achieve? Just by changing the width it also fits to 210px - is there a reason to be less than 210 or more than 300? Changing bg and text color is also easy, I really do not see what should be the goal.

Comment: @skobaljic Please see my above comment. The point of this question is to get an answer for all developers on how to apply ANY styling, period. Not anything regarding responsiveness.

Comment: Here's a fiddle showing the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/GVwZ4/4/ Basically, since the captcha is in an cross-domain iframe, it can't be styled with css or js. And the API ref doesn't explain how to make a custom theme. Regardless of whether a hacky solution exists, this should probably be submitted into the issue tracker.

Comment: @slicedtoad Part of me wonders if this is intentional. I mean, if anything messing with the iframe could trigger Google to think "i'm not a human", therefore defeating the entire purpose of the new version which was to make it so people didn't have to do captchas in the first place.

Comment: @AlexBeardsley But the single-origin-policy responsible for blocking iframe editing is a browser security measure for protecting _users_. It's quite easy to turn off. And if you were a bot, you wouldn't be using a browser in the first place.

Comment: )= So does that mean we can't do [this](https://i.imgur.com/CmOWlYu.png).

Comment: It was answered on a different question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73258010/5492980

Answer (score 158, accepted):

## Overview:

Sorry to be the answerer of bad news, but after research and debugging, it's pretty clear that there is no way to customize the styling of the new reCAPTCHA controls. The controls are wrapped in an `iframe`, which prevents the use of CSS to style them, and [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) prevents JavaScript from accessing the contents, ruling out even a hacky solution.

## Why No Customize API?:

Unlike [reCAPTCHA API Version 1.0](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/customization), there are no customize options in [API Version 2.0](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro). If we consider how this new API works, it's no surprise why.

#### Excerpt from [Are you a robot? Introducing “No CAPTCHA reCAPTCHA”](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/12/are-you-robot-introducing-no-captcha.html):

> While the new reCAPTCHA API may sound simple, there is a high degree of sophistication behind that modest checkbox. CAPTCHAs have long relied on the inability of robots to solve distorted text. However, our research recently showed that today’s Artificial Intelligence technology can solve even the most difficult variant of distorted text at 99.8% accuracy. Thus distorted text, on its own, is no longer a dependable test.
>
> To counter this, last year we developed an Advanced Risk Analysis backend for reCAPTCHA that actively considers a user’s entire engagement with the CAPTCHA—before, during, and after—to determine whether that user is a human. This enables us to rely less on typing distorted text and, in turn, offer a better experience for users.  We talked about this in our Valentine’s Day post earlier this year.

If you were able to directly manipulate the styling of the control elements, you could easily interfere with the user-profiling logic that makes the new reCAPTCHA possible.

## What About a Custom Theme?:

Now the new API [does offer a `theme` option](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#render_param), by which you can choose a preset theme such as `light` and `dark`. However there is not presently a way to create a custom theme. If we inspect the `iframe`, we will find the `theme` name is passed in the query string of the `src` attribute. This URL looks something like the following.

```
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?...&theme=dark&...
```

This parameter determines what CSS class name is used on the wrapper element in the `iframe` and determines the preset theme to use.

[image: element class name]

Digging through the minified source, I found that there are actually 4 valid theme values, which is more than the 2 listed in the documentation, but `default` and `standard` are the same as `light`.

[image: object of classes]

We can see the code that selects the class name from this object here.

[image: class choosing code]

There is no code for a custom theme, and if any other `theme` value is specified, it will use the `standard` theme.

## In Conclusion:

At present, there is no way to fully style the new reCAPTCHA elements, only the wrapper elements around the `iframe` can be stylized. This was almost-certainly done intentionally, to prevent users from breaking the user profiling logic that makes the new captcha-free checkbox possible. It is possible that Google could implement a limited custom theme API, perhaps allowing you to choose custom colors for existing elements, but I would not expect Google to implement full CSS styling.

Comment: That confirms what I found Alexander... was my initial frustration with the new reCAPTCHA, but it looks like there just isn't a way around that currently :(

Comment: Want to add link [How to resize the Google noCAPTCHA reCAPTCHA | The Geek Goddess](https://www.geekgoddess.com/how-to-resize-the-google-nocaptcha-recaptcha/), where author shared the trick to make Captcha v2 responsive.

Comment: would be nice to have at least a way to specify background and text color,

Comment: Further to themes. You can request the theme in the onCallback:

<script type="text/javascript">
  var onloadCallback = function() {
      grecaptcha.render('your_recaptcha_div_id', {
          'sitekey': 'your_site_key',
          theme: 'dark' <==========================
      });
  };
</script>

Comment: After a few years there is a solution: https://custom-captcha.js.org/

Answer (score 54):

As guys mentioned above, there is no way ATM. but still if anyone interested, then by adding in just two lines you can at least make it look reasonable, if it break on any screen. you can assign different value in @media query.

```
<div id="recaptchaContainer" style="transform:scale(0.8);transform-origin:0 0"></div>
```

Hope this helps anyone :-).

Comment: You can adjust the scale to whatever looks best for your particular layout. The transform-origin property is added because when you use the transform property, it doesn’t change the actual space taken up by the element.

That’s just a basic way to show how you can quickly change the size of the reCAPTCHA with inline styling. For something nicer, I’d suggest assigning a new class and leaving it at full size for anything above mobile, then using a media query to change it to the smaller size. Even better would be to use a transition effect so it visually “shrinks down” when you go to mobile.

Comment: You'll also want to use the browser specific rules, as iphones 5 don't recognize just "transform" it seems:   -ms-transform: scale(0.815);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.815);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.815);
  -o-transform: scale(0.815);
  transform: scale(0.815);

  -ms-transform-origin: left top;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
  -moz-transform-origin: left top;
  -o-transform-origin: left top;
     transform-origin: left top;

Answer (score 10):

I use below trick to make it responsive and remove borders. this tricks maybe hide recaptcha message/error.

This style is for rtl lang but you can change it easy.

```css
.g-recaptcha {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.g-recaptcha > * {
    float: right;
    right: 0;
    margin: -2px -2px -10px;/*remove borders*/ 
}

.g-recaptcha::after{
    display: block;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right:150px;
    top: 0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="Your Api Key"></div>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=fa'></script>
```

[image: recaptcha no captcha reponsive style trick]

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately we cant style reCaptcha v2, but it is possible to make it look better, here is the code:

[Click here to preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anf7W.png)

```
.g-recaptcha-outer{
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #37474f;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
}
.g-recaptcha-inner{
    width: 154px;
    height: 82px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.g-recaptcha{
    position:relative;
    left: -2px;
    top: -1px;
}

<div class="g-recaptcha-outer">
    <div class="g-recaptcha-inner">
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-size="compact" data-sitekey="YOUR KEY"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does not apply to the fallback recaptcha iframe for mobile users with non-JS browsers.

Answer (score 8):

Add a data-size property to the google recaptcha element and make it equal to "compact" in case of mobile.

Refer: [google recaptcha docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display)

Answer (score 5):

What you can do is to hide the ReCaptcha Control behind a div. Then make your styling on this div. And set the css "pointer-events: none" on it, so you can click through the div ([Click through a DIV to underlying elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements)).

The checkbox should be in a place where the user is clicking.

Answer (score 5):

I came across this answer trying to style the ReCaptcha v2 for a site that has a light and a dark mode. Played around some more and discovered that besides `transform`, `filter` is also applied to `iframe` elements so ended up using the default/light ReCaptcha and doing this when the user is in dark mode:

```
.g-recaptcha {
    filter: invert(1) hue-rotate(180deg);
}
```

The `hue-rotate(180deg)` makes it so that the logo is still blue and the check-mark is still green when the user clicks it, while keeping white `invert()`'ed to black and vice versa.

Didn't see this in any answer or comment so decided to share even if this is an old thread.

Answer (score 4):

You can recreate recaptcha , wrap it in a container and only let the checkbox visible. My main problem was that I couldn't take the full width so now it expands to the container width. The only problem is the expiration you can see a flick but as soon it happens I reset it.

See this demo http://codepen.io/alejandrolechuga/pen/YpmOJX

[image]

```js
function recaptchaReady () {
  grecaptcha.render('myrecaptcha', {
  'sitekey': '6Lc7JBAUAAAAANrF3CJaIjt7T9IEFSmd85Qpc4gj',
  'expired-callback': function () {
    grecaptcha.reset();
    console.log('recatpcha');
  }
});
}
```

```css
.recaptcha-wrapper {
    height: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
  height: 70px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 17px;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  color: #000;
}

.recaptcha-info {
  background-size: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 0 13px 0 13px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  top: 9px;
  width: 32px;
  background-image: url(https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/logo_48.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.rc-anchor-logo-text {
  color: #9b9b9b;
  cursor: default;
  font-family: Roboto,helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 37px;
}
.rc-anchor-checkbox-label {
  font-family: Roboto,helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 17px;
  left: 50px;
  top: 26px;
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
}
.rc-anchor .rc-anchor-normal .rc-anchor-light {
  border: none;
}
.rc-anchor-pt {
  color: #9b9b9b;
  font-family: Roboto,helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 8px;
  font-weight: 400;
  right: 10px;
  top: 53px;
  position: absolute;
  a:link {
    color: #9b9b9b;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

g-recaptcha {
  // transform:scale(0.95);
  // -webkit-transform:scale(0.95);
  // transform-origin:0 0;
  // -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;

}

.g-recaptcha {
  width: 41px;

  /* border: 1px solid red; */
  height: 38px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-left: 6px;
  
    > div {
    width: 46px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color:  #F9F9F9;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid red;
    transform: translate3d(-8px, -19px, 0px);
  }
  div {
    border: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=recaptchaReady&&render=explicit'></script>

<div class="recaptcha-wrapper">
  <div id="myrecaptcha" class="g-recaptcha"></div>
          <div class="rc-anchor-checkbox-label">I'm not a Robot.</div>
        <div class="recaptcha-info"></div>
        <div class="rc-anchor-logo-text">reCAPTCHA</div>
        <div class="rc-anchor-pt">
          <a href="https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/privacy/" target="_blank">Privacy</a>
          <span aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"> - </span>
          <a href="https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/" target="_blank">Terms</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your  Link is broken

Comment: Apparently Codepen removed it without my consent. Not sure if this could infringe a Codepen/Google policy.

Comment: After a few years there is a solution: https://custom-captcha.js.org/

Answer (score 3):

Great!
Now here is styling available for reCaptcha..
I just use inline styling like:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" style="transform: scale(1.08); margin-left: 14px;"></div>
```

whatever you wanna to do small customize in inline styling...

Hope it will help you!!

Answer (score 2):

Just adding a hack-ish solution to make it responsive.

Wrap the recaptcha in an extra div:

```
<div class="recaptcha-wrap">                   
    <div id="g-recaptcha"></div>
</div>
```

Add styles. This assumes the dark theme.

```
// Recaptcha
.recaptcha-wrap {
    position: relative;
    height: 76px;
    padding:1px 0 0 1px;
    background:#222;
    > div {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 2px;
        right:2px;
        font-size:10px;
        color:#ccc;
    }
}

// Hides top border
.recaptcha-wrap:after {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    background-color: #222;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    top: -1px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}

// Hides left border
.recaptcha-wrap:before {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    background-color: #222;
    height: 100%;
    width: 2px;
    top: 0;
    left: -1px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

// Makes it responsive & hides cut-off elements
#g-recaptcha {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 76px;
    border-right: 60px solid #222222;
    border-top: 1px solid #222222;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 294px;
}
```

This yields the following:

[image: Recaptcha]

It will now resize horizontally, and doesn't have a border. The recaptcha logo would get cut off on the right, so I am hiding it with a border-right. It's also hiding the privacy and terms links, so you may want to add those back in.

I attempted to set a height on the wrapper element, and then vertically center the recaptcha to reduce the height. Unfortunately, any combo of overflow:hidden and a smaller height seems to kill the iframe.

Comment: just tried your style, doesnt seem to work for me. -> http://jsfiddle.net/GVwZ4/31/

Answer (score 2):

in the V2.0 it's not possible. The iframe blocks all styling out of this. It's difficult to add a custom theme instead of the dark or light one.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but maybe my solution will help somebody.

I haven't found any solution that works on a responsive website when the viewport changes or the layout is fluid.

So I've created a jQuery script for django-cms that is dynamically adapting to a changing viewport. 
I'm going to update this response as soon as I have the need for a modern variant of it that is more modular and has no jQuery dependency.

**html**

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="{site_key}" data-size={size}> 
</div>
```

**css**

```
.g-recaptcha { display: none; }

.g-recaptcha.g-recaptcha-initted { 
    display: block; 
    overflow: hidden; 
}

.g-recaptcha.g-recaptcha-initted > * {
    transform-origin: top left;
}
```

**js**

```
window.djangoReCaptcha = {
    list: [],
    setup: function() {
        $('.g-recaptcha').each(function() {
            var $container = $(this);
            var config = $container.data();

            djangoReCaptcha.init($container, config);
        });

        $(window).on('resize orientationchange', function() {
            $(djangoReCaptcha.list).each(function(idx, el) {
                djangoReCaptcha.resize.apply(null, el);
            });
        });
    },
    resize: function($container, captchaSize) {
        scaleFactor = ($container.width() / captchaSize.w);
        $container.find('> *').css({
            transform: 'scale(' + scaleFactor + ')',
            height: (captchaSize.h * scaleFactor) + 'px'
        });
    },
    init: function($container, config) {
        grecaptcha.render($container.get(0), config);

        var captchaSize, scaleFactor;
        var $iframe = $container.find('iframe').eq(0);

        $iframe.on('load', function() {
            $container.addClass('g-recaptcha-initted');
            captchaSize = captchaSize || { w: $iframe.width() - 2, h: $iframe.height() };
            djangoReCaptcha.resize($container, captchaSize);
            djangoReCaptcha.list.push([$container, captchaSize]);
        });
    },
    lateInit: function(config) {
        var $container = $('.g-recaptcha.g-recaptcha-late').eq(0).removeClass('.g-recaptcha-late');
        djangoReCaptcha.init($container, config);
    }
};

window.djangoReCaptchaSetup = window.djangoReCaptcha.setup;
```

Answer (score 2):

With the integration of the invisible reCAPTCHA you can do the following:

> To enable the Invisible reCAPTCHA, rather than put the parameters in a div, you can add them directly to an html button.
>
> a. data-callback=””. This works just like the checkbox captcha, but is required for invisible.
>
> b. data-badge: This allows you to reposition the reCAPTCHA badge (i.e. logo and
> ‘protected by reCAPTCHA’ text) . Valid options as ‘bottomright’ (the default),
> ‘bottomleft’ or ‘inline’ which will put the badge directly above the button. If you
> make the badge inline, you can control the CSS of the badge directly.

Comment: When making the badge inline, how to directly control the CSS of the badge?

Answer (score 2):

In case someone struggling with the recaptcha of contact form 7 (wordpress) here is a solution working for me

```
.wpcf7-recaptcha{
clear: both;
float: left;
}
.wpcf7-recaptcha{
margin-right: 6px;
width: 206px;
height: 65px;
overflow: hidden;
border-right: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
}
.wpcf7-recaptcha iframe{
padding-bottom: 15px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
background: #F9F9F9;
border-left: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Lets play a little with JavaScript:

First at all, we know that recaptcha badget include all the shit from the most crazy people on Google, so you can only make changes with theme "dark" and "light" on your web.
Take a look to my website

[SantiagoSoñora](https://santiago.so%C3%B1ora.com).

```js
let recaptcha = document.querySelector('.g-recaptcha');
```

With this, you only can touch simple settings of the badge, like z-index and size, but no much more...

So far, i made two functions that set data-theme to light or dark mode at innit. Note that its neccessary assign the "light" because Google not include that by default.

```js
function reCaptchaDark() {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
        recaptcha.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark");
        })
    }

function reCaptchaLight() {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
        recaptcha.setAttribute("data-theme", "light");
        })
    }
```

Then, for example, my web looks if user prefers a dark or a light theme, and set that configurations to the recaptcha bag:

```js
(theme.onLoad = function() {
    if (window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) {
        reCaptchaDark();
        toggleTheme();
        }
    else {
        reCaptchaLight();
        }
    })();
```

Note that my code for toggle from dark to light is on the toggleTheme() function.
Keep doing magic: You should configure a class on the html tag or something else on your web for made the change between dark and light theme, and with that we now modify the src on the iframe so when we toggle dark/light mode ,with our button it changes:

```js
theme.onclick = function() {
    toggleTheme();
    if (html.classList.contains('dark')) {
        recaptcha.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark");
        setTimeout(function() {
            let iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
            iframes[0].src = iframes[0].src.replace('&theme=light', '&theme=dark');
            }, 0);
        }
    else {
        recaptcha.setAttribute("data-theme", "light");
        setTimeout(function() {
            let iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
            iframes[0].src = iframes[0].src.replace('&theme=dark', '&theme=light');
            }, 0);
        }
    }
```

And here you go, the recaptcha badge change from dark to light "preassigned" themes by Google bad guys.

And last but not least, a function that updates the page to change if your theme is dark by default.
This update the LocalStorage

```js
(function() {
    if( window.localStorage ) {
        if( !localStorage.getItem('firstLoad') ) {
            localStorage['firstLoad'] = true;
            window.location.reload();
        }  
        else
            localStorage.removeItem('firstLoad');
        }
    })();
```

You can use the class .grecaptcha-badge for some css changes, like opacity and box-shadow, -> (use !important)
Thats all, hope you can implement on your site

Answer (score 1):

if you use scss, that worked for me:

```
   .recaptcha > div{
      transform: scale(0.84);
      transform-origin: 0;
   }
```

Comment: Isn't it in essence the same answer as @bubb?

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still interested, there is a simple javascript library (no jQuery dependency), named custom recaptcha. It lets you customize the button with css and implement some js events (ready/checked). The idea is to make the default recaptcha "invisible" and put a button over it. Just change the id of the recaptcha and that's it.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://azentreprise.org/download/custom-recaptcha.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #captcha {
            float: left;
            margin: 2%;

            background-color: rgba(72, 61, 139, 0.5); /* darkslateblue with 50% opacity */
            border-radius: 2px;

            font-size: 1em;
            color: #C0FFEE;
        }

        #captcha.success {
            background-color: rgba(50, 205, 50, 0.5); /* limegreen with 50% opacity */
            color: limegreen;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="captcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key" data-label="Click here" data-label-spacing="15"></div>
</body>
```

See https://azentreprise.org/read.php?id=1 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I am just adding this kind of solution / quick fix so it won't get lost in case of a broken link.

Link to this solution ["Want to add link How to resize the Google noCAPTCHA reCAPTCHA | The Geek Goddess"](https://geekgoddess.com/how-to-resize-the-google-nocaptcha-recaptcha/) was provided by [Vikram Singh Saini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1041457/vikram-singh-saini) and simply outlines that you could use inline CSS to enforce framing of the iframe.

```
// Scale the frame using inline CSS
 <div class="g-recaptcha" data-theme="light" 
 data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXXXXXX" 

 style="transform:scale(0.77);
 -webkit-transform:scale(0.77);
 transform-origin:0 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;

 ">
</div> 

// Scale the images using a stylesheet
<style>
#rc-imageselect, .g-recaptcha {
  transform:scale(0.77);
  -webkit-transform:scale(0.77);
  transform-origin:0 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some CSS for **Google reCAPTCHA v2** styling on your website:

– Change background, color of Google reCAPTCHA v2 widget:

```
.rc-anchor-light { 
background: #fff!important; 
color: #fff!important; }
```

or

```
.rc-anchor-normal{
background: #000 !important; 
color: #000 !important; }
```

– Resize the Google reCAPTCHA v2 widget by using this snippet:

```
.rc-anchor-light { 
transform:scale(0.9); 
-webkit-transform:scale(0.9); }
```

– Responsive your Google reCAPTCHA v2:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.rc-anchor-light { 
transform:scale(0.85); 
-webkit-transform:scale(0.85); } 
}
```

All elements, property of CSS above that’s just for your reference. You can change them by yourself (only using CSS class selector).

Refer on OIW Blog - *How To Edit CSS of Google reCAPTCHA (Re-style, Change Position, Resize reCAPTCHA Badge)*

You can also find out Google reCAPTCHA v3's styling there.

Comment: CSS is only scoped within the same document. An iframe is an entire document in its own right, and so a CSS rule that applies to the page that contains that iframe cannot apply to the page that's within that iframe.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but I tried this and it worked to make the Recaptcha responsive on screens smaller than 460px width. You can't use css selector to select elements inside the iframe. So, better use the outermost parent element which is the class g-recaptcha to basically zoom-out i.e transform the size of the entire container. Here's my code which worked:

```
@media(max-width:459.99px) {
    .modal .g-recaptcha {
        transform:scale(0.75);
        -webkit-transform:scale(0.75); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase someone wants to resize recaptcha for small devices.

I was using recaptcha V2 with primeng `p-captcha` (for angular). The issue was that for smaller screens it would go out of the screen.

Although you can't actually resize it (the external thing and all everyone has explained it above) but there is a way with `transform` property (scaling the the container)

**this was my code below the way, I achieved it**

```
p-captcha div div {
  transform:scale(0.9) !important;
  -webkit-transform:scale(0.9) !important;
  transform-origin:0 0 !important;
  -webkit-transform-origin:0 0 !important;
}
```

Other than `p-captcha` you can use this code snippet below

```
.g-recaptcha {
  transform:scale(0.9);
  transform-origin:0 0;
 }
```

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Topic is old, but I also wanted to scale the reCAPTCHA widget -- but to make it **bigger** for phone users, unlike many others who wanted it smaller.  The only way that worked was transform: scale(x), but that seemed to make the widget too wide for my page, thus shrinking the rest of the form on the page.  Using a container div as shown below fixed my problem, and hopefully it will help someone else who thinks a bigger version is better on a small screen.

```html
<style>
    :root {
        /* factor to scale the Google widget in potrait mode (on a phone) */
        --recaptcha-scale: 2; 
    }
    @media screen and (orientation: portrait) {

        /* needed to rein in the width of inner div when it is scaled */
        #g_recaptcha_div_container { 
            width: calc(100vmin / var(--recaptcha-scale));
        }
        #g_recaptcha_div {
            transform: scale(var(--recaptcha-scale)); 
            transform-origin: 0 0;
        }
        #submit_button {
            width: 65vmin;
            height: 9vmin;
            font-size: 7vmin;

            /* needed to scoot the button out from under the scaled div */
            margin-top: 10vmin; 
        }
    }
</style>
```

```html
<html>
<!-- top of form with a bunch of fields to create an acct -->

    <div id="g_recaptcha_div_container">
        <div id="g_recaptcha_div" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="foo">
        </div>
    </div>

    <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Create Account">

<!-- bottom of form -->
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to color it with this css filter hack:

```
.colorize-pink {
  filter: brightness(0.5) sepia(1) hue-rotate(-70deg) saturate(5);
}

.colorize-navy {
  filter: brightness(0.2) sepia(1) hue-rotate(180deg) saturate(5);
}
```

and for the size, use transform css hack

```
 .captcha-size {
transform:scale(0.8);transform-origin:0 0
    }
```