# How to change div elements' css inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I've found here in SO these two ways to manipulate css style od div elements inside an iframe:

```
jQuery("iframe").contents().find(".rc-anchor-normal-footer").css("margin-left", "-60px");
```

and

```
jQuery("iframe").load(function() {
    var doc = this.contentDocument || this.contentWindow.document;
    var ancor_footer = document.getElementsByClassName("rc-anchor-normal-footer");
    ancor_footer[0].style.marginLeft = "-60px";
});
```

They both were put inside the `jQuery(document).ready(function(){})` but none of them works. If i try to give those commands inside firebug JS console I get

> jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.pasticceriaimpero.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

even if I had set

```
document.domain = "www.pasticceriaimpero.it"
```

Wham am I supposed to do to make it work?

**UPDATE**
I managed to manipulate `g-recaptcha` style with the following:

```
@media not screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 3/4) {
.g-recaptcha {
  margin-top: 2px !important;
  transform:scale(0.78);
  transform-origin:0 0;
}
```

and witout accessing every single sub div of the recaptcha with jQuery...

Comment: You can't change **anything** inside an iFrame that loads a page where domain, port or protocol does not match the parent page, it's called the same-origin policy.

Comment: If your domain is NOT pasticceriaimpero.it which is what you need to set, then it is wishful thinking. visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: Maybe I forgot to say that the div I would like to change is Google recaptcha `<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcjFgoUAAAAAG7kjR01GaS7-bS-ZOvZL2eMiGyC"></div`. is this the reason why?

Comment: This https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/customization can help?

Comment: Thank you mate. I'm going to have a look! :)

Comment: Ops too fast, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713505/recaptcha-api-v2-styling