# Is it possible to edit the CSS of a Google-generated CAPTCHA?

Tags: css, wordpress, recaptcha, captcha, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm in the process of adding Google CAPTCHAs to 3 different Gravity Forms on a Wordpress website. I've integrated everything successfully and all appears to be working, but I am running into problems overriding Google's CSS in order to customize the CAPTCHA appearance. This is particularly problematic when it comes to sizing, as the CAPTCHAs aren't mobile responsive and in one instance it spills over my sidebar and into the site content (which I've removed for now, while troubleshooting).

Any guidance you can offer about how to go about changing the style/size of the CAPTCHA would be much appreciated!

Comment: No, you can’t change its style.

Comment: The question is answer and sorry, you can't: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28619922/8329480

Comment: Ahh, that's what I was afraid of. Okay, thank you!