# How to customize style of React Recaptcha?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, recaptcha

I am using [this](https://github.com/appleboy/react-recaptcha) package in my `React` application.

The problem is when running the application in a specific device `Galaxy Fold`, the container of selecting images is too big.

I need to change the size of the div with this id `rc-imageselect`.

Here is my code

```
        <div className={classes.recapt} style={{ transform: 'scale(0.8, 0.8) translateX(10%)', display: "table" }}>
          <Recaptcha
            expiredCallback={() => setCaptchaCode(false)}
            sitekey={localStorage.getItem("CAPTCHA_KEY")}
            render="explicit"
            onloadCallback={callback}
            verifyCallback={verifyCallback}
          />
        </div>

   export default makeStyles((theme) => ({
    recapt: {
      "&div": {
        "&#rc-imageselect": {
            transform: 'scale(0.8, 0.8) translateX(10%)'
        }
       }
    }
   }));
```

But this doesn't work.

I changed it in te inspect panel and it works. So my guess I am selection the `div` in a wrong way.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your style targeting has problem, try like this :

```
"& > div > image"
```

And i think u cannot using query (#elementID) on that .

**Edit**

After uploading photo : Take look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28619922/12608714)

Comment: that's not working. Please notice that the target should 'rc-imageselect' which is an id not a class

Comment: @Amine can u make screen shot from element u want target?

Comment: I uploaded it .

Comment: @Amine u cannot target id or class on this, u should target element by tagname

Comment: The tag name is div

Comment: So it can't be styled ?

Comment: in your case u should try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30376755/12608714 maybe it works. good luck.

Comment: Thank you I am already implementing this as it affects only the initial container