# Recaptcha v3 dark theme

Tags: recaptcha-v3

Is there a possibility to use a dark theme for google recaptcha 3?
I tried to add `data-theme="dark"` in `grecaptcha` block but it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

Have you try this?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  const recaptcha = document.querySelector('.g-recaptcha');
  recaptcha.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark");
});
```

Or you can change it manually by find the div with class `g-recaptcha` and add the attribute `data-theme="dark"`.

Comment: Hm, maybe you can try this tutorial https://ohiwill.com/how-to-edit-css-of-google-recaptcha-re-style-change-position-resize-recaptcha-badge/

Comment: Ok, so there is only one way to change the style - by adding custom css styles, ok, there is no other choice, thank's

Comment: It doesn't help too, because we cannot change styles in iframe

Answer (score 0):

I made this way, actually i made some modifications, but i can't made the badge turn black on first load, i'll still make a refresh for that.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72502375/17791142

i wish this can help you.